# Display all the "if statements " in a file using "grep"

Tags: grep

I have a file "file.txt" that contains a number of `if`-statements as shown below:

```
if ( x == y)

if (x == (y + 1))

and so on.
```

How to display all the `if`-statements present in the file on the screen using `grep`.

I tried:  `grep -R "if ( * == * )" *` but it's not showing the required result.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to [*glob*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). `grep` uses [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Using [GNU Grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/):

```
grep -n '\<if\s*(' file.txt
```

This looks for `if` at the start of a word, followed by optional (`*`) whitespace `(\s`) and an opening parenthesis (`(`).

---

If you only want to see tests for equivalence, you can do:

```
grep -n '\<if\s*(.*==' file.txt
```

...this adds a check for zero-to-many (`*`) (wildcard) characters (`.`) between `(` and `==` but this won't catch multiline tests like:

```
if (status != OFF &&
    volume == 11) 
{
    // [...]
}
```

---

If you only want to test for *assignment*:

```
grep -n '\<if\s*(.*[^!<>=+*/^-]=[^=]' test.txt
```

...this checks that the character before the `=` is not (`^`) and of `!<>=+*/^-` (`[]`) and that the character immediately afterward isn't an `=`.

This is not flawless, but I'm sure you can tweak the regular expression yourself to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks John for response. But its displaying all types of "if statements". It should NOT show "if ( x < y)" or "if ( x & y )" etc.. it should only show "if ( x == Y)" types of statements.

Comment: Thanks John. It works. Next questions is : how to display only "if ( x = y)" ?   only single "=".   It should not even display "==" type if statements. I want to check how many such single "="  'if' statements are there in my file.

Comment: @santosh: Why didn't you *ask* that up front? Please take a read of http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and see how you can get the right answer first time. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: Thanks John once again. I needed answers for both the questions but "==" was more important. i.e "if (x==y)" was  more important. Thats why I have created the topic accordingly. Regards

Comment: @santosh: I'll let you off since you're new. The key here is "both the questions". You only asked one above. New questions should be posted as new questions on StackOverflow. And the most helpful answer to the question asked should be accepted using the ✓ next to the answer (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)).